# Sticky header on scroll in Microsoft Edge

Tags: jquery, header, microsoft-edge, sticky, onscroll

I have an full width element that on page load is off the screen but as a user scrolls down the page, the element moves up as a typical scroll should.

Once this element reaches the top of page I want it to stick to top and be the header for rest of page to scroll under.

I have this working on all browsers except for Microsoft Edge. I tried the snippets of code below without success on Edge. I also tried setting the scroll distance to a set number of px but that didn't work due to varying heights of browser and devices.

I'm grasping for anything now, does anyone have possible solutions I could try? Mahalo!

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
if ($(window).scrollTop() > $(window).height() ) {
    $('#systemSticky').removeClass('sticky');
} else {
    $('#systemSticky').addClass('sticky');
}
});
```

--and this---

```
var stickyOffset = $('#systemSticky').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
var sticky = $('#systemSticky'),
  scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

if (scroll >= stickyOffset) sticky.addClass('fixed');
 else sticky.removeClass('fixed');
});
```

---and this---

```
$(document).scroll(function() {
var scrollDistance = $(document).scrollTop();
var stickyMenu = $("#systemSticky");
if(stickyMenu.offset().top == 0)  {
    stickyMenu.addClass({
        "position": "fixed",
        "top" : "0",
        "width" : "100%"
    });
} else {
    stickyMenu.css("position", "relative");
}
});
```

---and this---

```
var header = $("#systemSticky");
$(window).scroll(function() {
var scroll = window.scrollTop();
if (scroll = 100vh) {
    header.addClass("position: fixed");
} else {
    header.removeClass("position: fixed");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function sticky_relocate() {
 var window_top = $(window).scrollTop();
 var div_top = $('#sticky-anchor').offset().top;
 if (window_top > div_top) {
    $('#sticky').addClass('stick');
    $('#sticky-anchor').height($('#sticky').outerHeight());
 } else {
    $('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
    $('#sticky-anchor').height(0);
 }
}

$(function() {
    $(window).scroll(sticky_relocate);
    sticky_relocate();
});
```

On this HTML:

```
<div id="sticky-anchor"></div>
<div id="sticky">This will stay at top of page</div>
```

And add this to your CSS:

```
#sticky {
    padding: 0.5ex;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2em;
    border-radius: 0.5ex;
}

#sticky.stick {
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    border-radius: 0 0 0.5em 0.5em;
}
```

When the if statement is true it will apply a new class to the already existing class. So you can adjust every style you want when the div hits the top of the window (in this case).

For further explanation visit this [post](http://blog.yjl.im/2010/01/stick-div-at-top-after-scrolling.html), and look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HV9HM/7249/)